# Bot responding too slow after first message

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a bot built using Microsoft Boatbuilder and node.js, hosted on Azure. The bot works fine and responds almost instantly when a single user says "Hi". But we have observed that when multiple users are trying to chat, the bot takes anywhere between 30 sec to 1 minute to respond to the first message.

We checked the application logs but there is nothing in there that can explain the cause of this delay.

Comment: Just to clarify, this happens when multiple users are using the bot, but when only one user is using it, then it works fine? How custom is the code at this point? Is it based off of a [https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs](sample), or from a web app bot template? Have you tried creating a _new_ Web App Bot from the Azure portal template (using Node), and does that behave in the same manner?

Comment: @DanaV Yes, the bot works fine when a single user is using it. And yes the code is mostly built using the samples of bot builder. It has MySQL database integration and a separate JS file included to pull some values. Rest is pretty much bot.dialog. session.send, and if/else conditions.

Comment: I wonder if you are hitting the issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/183#issuecomment-467595274). Are you able to test the same scenario with a .NET bot?

Comment: @MuhammadOmarKhan Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be to enable the Always On feature in the bot's appservice.

Comment: It's already set to Always On [Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/LDiyQo5smxZ)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and found turning the app service to Always On reduced our first message latency massively.

If you go to your Azure portal, then navigate to:

> Dashboard --> App Services --> [name of service] --> Configuration -->
>   General Settings

there's an Always On option you can check 'yes' to.

Comment: It's already set to Always On [Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/LDiyQo5smxZ)